# Teradata Sql assistant not running SELECT statements

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, teradata

I am trying to run the follwoing sql queries in Teradata sql assistants :

```
DECLARE @myTablVar TABLE ( tablename varchar(100) )
INSERT INTO @myTablVar VALUES('?')
SELECT * from @myTablVar
```

Info:

1. I do not have permission to create tables. So I created the table variable.
2. I am using Teradata's Importa data feature to insert values into the table variable @myTablVar. There is only one column in the source file.
3. The system is configured someway such that sql server 2008 queries run only.

Issue:

1. When I run this, data are imported but the select statement is not
   running, and so I can not see the result.
2. If I put semicoln after each statement then one error occurs :

> "Only 1 statement is allowed for this type of import"

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Assistant Import mode submits the entire query, as a single request, for each record in the Import file.
I'm not sure if SQL Server will like those 3 statements submitted multiple times.

If it is allowed, then the results of the Select statement will be written to a file - not returned to the application display.
Imports never return data to the display - they always write the results to a file whose name is composed of the Import file name plus '.log'. It will be located in the same directory as the Import file.

I don't know a lot about SQL Server 2008 but if it will keep the declared table between queries you could submit the Import first. Then submit the Select after it completes.

Note that prior to version 15.0 Import always submits the entire contents ofthe query window even if you have part of the query highlighted and you have the option set to submit only the highlighted part of a query. (That option did not apply to Import mode until version 15.)